# Apache myfaces trinidad with Jsf 2.0 Tutorial

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I am searching for a tutorial for using apache myfaces trinidad with Jsf 2.0. Can somebody please provide a link for this.

Comment: Developer's guide ? http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/index.html

Comment: @Andy the developer guide only covers JSF 1